The Homotopy Type of $Emb(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$
I have encountered two statements respect to the homotopy type of  $Emb(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$.
One is that it is homotopically equivalent to $O(n)$ via Gram Schmidt Process. Another is that it is the configuration space of 1 point on $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, they are clearly not the same. Therefore, what am I missing?

The first one is correct. What is the reference to the 2nd one? Incidentally, you should state that your embeddings are in the smooth category.

Thank you for the comment. I guess I might have mixed the concept of rectilinear embedding of disks with the smooth embedding.
